# How to fix routing issue in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, routes, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

im trying to access "http://localhost:3000/login" and made a login.jsx in the pages folder in "testproject\pages\login.jsx".

Inside login.jsx is a simply

```
import React from 'react'

const Login = () => {
  return (
    <div>Login</div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

It was working fine (was able to see "Login" on the blank page), then it stopped when I accidentally deleted my 'pages' folder. (made a new pages folder and coded login the same way).

is there a way to fix this?

Now when I go to "http://localhost:3000/login", it only shows a blank white page.

The things I tried but were unsuccessful:
Changed pages directory to "testproject\app\pages\login.jsx"
Recover the deleted pages folder.

Comment: Are you sure that you creates the `pages` folder in the correct location?

Comment: try removing `.next` folder and then start your app

Comment: If you are using App new router you don't need to have pages folder inside app folder, for routes you're using app folder or pages folder depends on your choice with create-next-app, try using one of theme and delete .next folder

Comment: deleted .next file and restarted the app but couldn't fix it. Anyways, I used the app folder theme instead for my pages and it works fine now. Thank you all